# Random movement and rotation of Rectangle shape in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create a game on html canvas where I have a car I can control. And there will be some other cars controlled by computer. I can control my car with the four Arrow keys (up, down, left, right). And it’s working fine. I am facing some difficulties generating other opponent cars which will move randomly within the canvas area and take sharp turn like the car I am controlling with four arrow keys.

I have done some codes to make the movement of the random generated cars. But these are not working properly. Movement are not smooth, random and the cars are not turning right or left properly.

Initially I am displaying a rectangle instead of car. Green rectangles are the computer controlled car and the blue one is controlled by user.

Anyone has any idea to solve the problem? I am totally stuck here. Thanks in advance.

My js file is given below.

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 500;
const canvasW = canvas.width;
const canvasH = canvas.height;

let upPressed = false,
  downPressed = false,
  rightPressed = false,
  leftPressed = false;

let enemies = [];

class PlayerCar {
  constructor(carX, carY, carWidth, carHeight) {
    this.carX = carX;
    this.carY = carY;
    this.carWidth = carWidth;
    this.carHeight = carHeight;
    this.angle = 0;
    this.rot = 0.1; //control how fast it turns
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.translate(this.carX, this.carY);
    ctx.rotate(this.angle);
    ctx.rect(
      -this.carWidth / 2,
      -this.carHeight / 2,
      this.carWidth,
      this.carHeight
    );
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
  }
  update() {
    if (rightPressed) {
      this.angle += this.rot;
    } else if (leftPressed) {
      this.angle -= this.rot;
    }
    if (upPressed) {
      this.carX += Math.cos(this.angle + toRadians(-90)) * 5;
      this.carY += Math.sin(this.angle + toRadians(-90)) * 5;
    }
    if (downPressed) {
      this.carX += Math.cos(this.angle + toRadians(90)) * 5;
      this.carY += Math.sin(this.angle + toRadians(90)) * 5;
    }
  }
}

class EnemyCar {
  constructor(carX, carY, carWidth, carHeight) {
    this.carX = carX;
    this.carY = carY;
    this.carWidth = carWidth;
    this.carHeight = carHeight;
    this.angle = 0;
    this.rot = 0.1;
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(this.carX, this.carY, this.carWidth, this.carHeight);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
  }
  update() {
    if (this.carX < 0) this.carX = 0;
    if (this.carX > canvasW - this.carWidth)
      this.carX = canvasW - this.carWidth;
    if (this.carY < 0) {
      this.carY = 0;
    }
    if (this.carY > canvasH - this.carHeight) {
      this.carY = canvasH - this.carHeight;
    }

    let test = Math.random() * 30;
    if (test < 5) {
      this.angle += this.rot;
    } else if (test > 5 && test < 10) {
      this.angle -= this.rot;
    }
    if (test > 10 && test < 20) {
      this.carX += Math.cos(this.angle + toRadians(-90)) * 5;
      this.carY += Math.sin(this.angle + toRadians(-90)) * 5;
    }
    if (test > 20 && test < 30) {
      this.carX += Math.cos(this.angle + toRadians(-90)) * 5;
      this.carY += Math.sin(this.angle + toRadians(-90)) * 5;
    }
  }
}

function toRadians(deg) {
  return (deg * Math.PI) / 180;
}

const playerCar = new PlayerCar(200, 100, 40, 60);
playerCar.draw();

function navigation() {
  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
      upPressed = true;
    }
    if (e.key === "ArrowDown") {
      downPressed = true;
    }
    if (e.key === "ArrowRight") {
      rightPressed = true;
    }
    if (e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
      leftPressed = true;
    }
  };

  const handleKeyUp = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
      upPressed = false;
    }
    if (e.key === "ArrowDown") {
      downPressed = false;
    }
    if (e.key === "ArrowRight") {
      rightPressed = false;
    }
    if (e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
      leftPressed = false;
    }
  };

  document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
  document.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
}

function spawnEnemy() {
  enemies.push(new EnemyCar(Math.floor(canvasW / 4), 400, 40, 60));
  enemies.push(new EnemyCar(Math.floor(canvasW / 2), 400, 40, 60));
  enemies.push(new EnemyCar(Math.floor(canvasW / 1.33), 400, 40, 60));
}

spawnEnemy();

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasW, canvasH);

  if (playerCar.carX < 0) playerCar.carX = 0;
  if (playerCar.carX > canvasW - playerCar.carWidth)
    playerCar.carX = canvasW - playerCar.carWidth;
  if (playerCar.carY < 0) {
    playerCar.carY = 0;
  }
  if (playerCar.carY > canvasH) {
    playerCar.carY = canvasH;
  }

  enemies.forEach((enemy) => {
    enemy.draw();
    enemy.update();
  });

  playerCar.draw();
  playerCar.update();
}

function startGame() {
  animate();
}

function drawCC() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(100, 200, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
}

startGame();
navigation();
```